# Server Not Found Error

Tags: asp.net, web

I am new to web programming, and want to set up Hello World on my web site.
I have web.config as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and index.html as

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Sample "Hello, World" Application</title>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor=white>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
   <tr>
    <td>
      <h1>Sample "Hello, World" Application</h1>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p>This is the home page for World. </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

however when I go to www.mywebsite.com   I get a server not found error.

Where am I going wrong?  Am I missing a file?

Comment: Have you set up the DNS entries to point the domain name to the server? Does the server know how to respond to that host name? (i.e. is IIS configured to accept that as a host header, or accept anything on that IP address).

Comment: DNS was disabled. Enableing it now. I have also discovered an instant Alias which is working.  Do I just need to wait for DNS propegation? Do I need to double check my DNS records?

Comment: As already said DNS doesn't set. It takes a while for DNS servers to get updated till then you can use IP (if own a dedicated).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are learning to write code. If that is the case, then use your hosts file to create a custom domain name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

probably in %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Editing a host file is very easy.

If you are learning to administer computers (by setting up iis, configure ip addresses, domain names, etc) then you want to continue on the path of learning about DNS. SeverFault may have more advice, I'm not sure.

Comment: It is setting up websites using DNS I want to learn about.  I am a winforms programmer - but a bit new to setting up web sites.